# Variable Arguement With Class Reference As 1st Parameter

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a {
};

void fun1(a& aa, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, aa);
    char *p = 0;
    while ((p = va_arg(argp, char *)) != 0) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    va_end(argp);
}

void fun2(char *aa, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, aa);
    char *p = 0;
    while ((p = va_arg(argp, char *)) != 0) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    va_end(argp);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "fun2" << endl;
    fun2("a", "1", "2", (char *)0);
    cout << "fun1" << endl;
    fun1(a(), "1", "2", (char *)0);
    getchar();
}
```

Everything works fine with fun2. However, fun1 will just crash.

May I know how can I prevent from crashing, at the same time able to use class reference as 1st parameter.

Currently, it prints :

```
fun2
1
2
fun1
```

then crash.

I wish

```
fun2
1
2
fun1
1
2
```

Comment: How do you expect that varargs to work?

Comment: You said you have up in a comment, so i take it you cant switch to gcc? alternatively you can compile some code in a dll and call it in msvc but i hate that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a reference parameter as the last named parameter with va_start.  The reason is because va_start takes the address of the named parameter to find the location of the rest of the arguments.  However, taking the address of a reference gives the address of the variable pointed at by the reference, not the address of the parameter itself.  Your options are:

1) change the variable type from a reference to a pointer (or a non-reference if you are OK with a copy of the passed in variable).

2) Add an additional required parameter so that the reference isn't the last named parameter.  The additional parameter can be a useful parameter, such as one of the char* you are going to pass to your particular function, or it can be a dummy variable you just ignore.

3) Change the definition of va_start.  It's not recommended, but you can do it.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119394 for a non-portable redefinition.

Comment: Ick - good catch Darryl. Yet another reason to avoid varargs like the plague.

Comment: ref as va_params seem to work with gcc (see my answer and codepad). Nice point about the address problem. +1

Comment: OK. I gave up. There are no easy way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're crashing in `fun2`.

Because you're calling `va_arg` too many times and screwing up the stack.

You must only call `va_arg` the same number of times as there are parameters.

Comment: No. I am only crashing in fun1 (Note that my calling sequence is fun2 followed by fun1). My implementation is referring http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html

Comment: You'll notice that `fun1` is never output. Thus, your code is not returning from `fun2`. Also, I think this highlights the dangers of copy-pasting code you don't understand.

Comment: OK. I fix according to D.Shawley comment. But it crash still in fun1.

Answer (score 2):

Both `fun1` and `fun2` terminate the loop when they encounter a `NULL` or `0` parameter.  You are never passing one.  Change `main` to:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "fun2" << endl;
    fun2("a", "1", "2", NULL);
    cout << "fun1" << endl;
    fun1(a(), "1", "2", NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

<strike>**Note** I haven't compiled this, but it should work.  You may have to follow [janm's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106786/variable-arguement-with-class-reference-as-1st-parameter/2106808#2106808) as well.</strike>

**Update**: I set down and thought about this again. You have to either:

1. Instantiate an object of type `a` inside of `main` and pass it or...
2. Following [janm's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106786/variable-arguement-with-class-reference-as-1st-parameter/2106808#2106808) and change `a& aa` in `fun2` to `a const& aa`

When I tried to compile the original under g++, I was greeted with the following error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'a&' from a
>          temporary of type 'a' 
>   error: in passing argument 1 of 'void fun1(a&, ...)'

Essentially, you cannot pass a temporary variable as a non-`const` reference.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/non-const-reference-to-temporary-object) and [this Herb Sutter GotW](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) for some of the gory details.

Comment: Thanks. It no longer crashing at fun2. But it still crash at fun1.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a non-const reference to a temporary.  Change the fun1 prototype to:

```
void fun1(a const& aa, ...)
```

Update:

Haven't used varargs for a long time, missed that a terminating parameter wasn't being passed.  See [D. Shawley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106786/variable-arguement-with-class-reference-as-1st-parameter/2106917#2106917); you must pass a terminating parameter if you're going to use that as your interface.

Comment: It crash still. I am using VC++ 2008. Does it crash on your side?

Comment: Just checked on OSX and FreeBSD; works but by coincidence. You must pass a terminating null to terminate your argument processing loop. The actual best approach is to not use varargs at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear this code doesnt work. I notice if fun2(aa is a ptr instead of a ref the code works. I also notice while trying to compile on gcc (via http://codepad.org/) you pass "a" into fun2 which is a char*. codepad/gcc complained about it not being a const char*. In codepad this code works. In my copy of VS2008 it crashes and 2010b2 as well.

My recommendation is to avoid va params but i'll assume you can't so i suggest not to use ref and use pointers. Or switch to gcc but i wouldnt do that unless there are no other (reasonable) option.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class a {
};

void fun1(a& aa, ...)
{
    //cout<< "sizeof" << sizeof(aa) << "&aa == " << &aa;
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, aa);
    char *p = 0;
    while ((p = va_arg(argp, char *)) != 0) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    va_end(argp);
}

void fun2(const char *aa, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, aa);
    char *p = 0;
    while ((p = va_arg(argp, char *)) != 0) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    va_end(argp);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "fun2" << endl;
    fun2("a", "1", "2", 0);
    cout << "fun1" << endl;
    a aa;
    //cout<< "sizeof" << sizeof(aa) << "&aa == " << &aa;
    fun1(aa, "1", "2", 0);
    getchar();
}
```